# Numpy append list to array without merging them

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Having an empty array

```
x = numpy.empty(0)
```

And two lists that looks like this

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]
```

how do i add to the empty array the lists so that it becomes something like this

```
np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

instead of

```
np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

which is what happens when i use

```
x = np.append(x, l1)
x = np.append(x, l2)
```

Comment: You could simply do `x = np.array([l1, l2])`, and in case you need to append frequently, I would suggest appending it to a list and then convert to array when you need to. `np.append` is more expensive that `list.append`.

Comment: What is your use-case, why are you defining `x = numpy.empty(0)` in the first place?

Comment: FWIW, if you want to use `np.append` the code will be: `x = np.empty((0,3));x = np.append(x, [l1], axis=0);x = np.append(x, [l2], axis=0)`

Comment: You didn't read the `append` docs carefully.enough!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use [`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) to stack arrays in sequence vertically:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]


x = np.vstack([l1, l2])
print(x)
```

This results:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np

x = []
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]

x.append(l1)
x.append(l2)

x = np.array(x)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all convert the lists to numpy arrays to work more flexible

```
from numpy import *
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]
l1_np = asarray(l1)
l2_np = asarray(l2)
l = concatenate([l1_np,l2_np])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reshape to help make the append operation automatically

```
l1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
l2 = np.array([4, 5, 6])
l=np.concatenate([l1,l2])
l.reshape((2,3))
```

outputs:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```